# DotNet Core EnsureBindingRedirects task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to build a .Net Core project, that uses Microsoft.Bcl.Build in version 1.0.14, with the following targets file:

```
<!--
***********************************************************************************************
Microsoft.Bcl.targets

WARNING:  DO NOT MODIFY this file unless you are knowledgeable about MSBuild and have
          created a backup copy.  Incorrect changes to this file will make it
          impossible to load or build your projects from the command-line or the IDE.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
***********************************************************************************************
-->
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <BclBuildImported>true</BclBuildImported>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' != 'Silverlight' and '$(OutputType)' != 'AppContainerExe'">
    <!-- 
      Workaround MSBuild issue that prevents System.Runtime 2.5 and System.Threading.Tasks 2.5 from
      satisfying indirect dependencies on System.Runtime 1.5 and System.Threading.Tasks 1.5 respectively.  
    -->
    <AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>false</AutoUnifyAssemblyReferences>

    <!-- MSBuild by default doesn't pass the Web.Config ResolveAssemblyReference, in which case, set it so that it sees binding redirects -->
    <AppConfig Condition="'$(AppConfig)' == '' And '$(WebProjectOutputDir)' != '' And Exists('$(ProjectConfigFileName)')">$(ProjectConfigFileName)</AppConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- Workaround issue that incorrectly unifies references not in the current profile to the version in the superset of all profiles. -->
  <Target Name="_BclBuildSetFullFrameworkFolderToProfile" AfterTargets="GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETPortable'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths>$(TargetFrameworkDirectory)</_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <!--
    *******************************************************************************************************************
    *******************************************************************************************************************
                                                                                         EnsureBindingRedirects Section
    *******************************************************************************************************************
    *******************************************************************************************************************
    -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <__IntermediateAppConfig>$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(MSBuildProjectFile).App.config</__IntermediateAppConfig>

    <SkipEnsureBindingRedirects Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Silverlight' or '$(OutputType)' == 'AppContainerExe'">true</SkipEnsureBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <UsingTask TaskName="EnsureBindingRedirects" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll" />

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                  BclBuildDetermineReferencesToRedirect

    Determine which references are opted in for binding redirects
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="BclBuildDetermineReferencesToRedirect" BeforeTargets="BclBuildEnsureBindingRedirects" Condition="'$(SkipEnsureBindingRedirects)' != 'true'">
    <!-- Convention is a file next to the reference with name "ensureRedirect.xml" -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <_EnsureBindingRedirectReference Include="@(Reference)"
                                       Condition="'%(Reference.HintPath)' != '' and Exists('$([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName(&quot;%(Reference.HintPath)&quot;))\\ensureRedirect.xml')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                         BclBuildEnsureBindingRedirects

    Generate a new app.config with merged binding redirects if we have binding redirects to ensure and it's out of date
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="BclBuildEnsureBindingRedirects"
          DependsOnTargets="BclBuildDetermineReferencesToRedirect"
          BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"
          Condition="'@(_EnsureBindingRedirectReference)' != '' and '$(SkipEnsureBindingRedirects)' != 'true'"
          Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);$(AppConfig);@(_EnsureBindingRedirectReference->'%(HintPath)')"
          Outputs="$(__IntermediateAppConfig)">

    <EnsureBindingRedirects References="@(_EnsureBindingRedirectReference->'%(HintPath)')"
                            SourceAppConfigPath="$(AppConfig)"
                            DestinationAppConfigPath="$(__IntermediateAppConfig)">
      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationAppConfigPath" ItemName="FileWrites"/>
    </EnsureBindingRedirects>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                  BclBuildUpdateAppConfigWithTargetPath

    Update project properties to point to the generated app.config
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="BclBuildUpdateAppConfigWithTargetPath"
          DependsOnTargets="BclBuildDetermineReferencesToRedirect;BclBuildEnsureBindingRedirects"
          BeforeTargets="ResolveAssemblyReferences"
          Condition="'@(_EnsureBindingRedirectReference)' != '' and '$(SkipEnsureBindingRedirects)' != 'true'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <AppConfig>$(__IntermediateAppConfig)</AppConfig>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="@(AppConfigWithTargetPath)" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(AppConfig)">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>


  <!--
    *******************************************************************************************************************
    *******************************************************************************************************************
                                                                                      ValidatePackageReferences Section

    This group of targets enables validation of nuget package references when building inside VisualStudio.
    *******************************************************************************************************************
    *******************************************************************************************************************
    -->

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                  BclBuildAddProjectReferenceProperties

    Adds properties to be set when resolving project references.  The properties ensure that the references get built
    in the context of the referencer (by changing the set of properties used to build the project) and pass down the
    context needed to validate the referencing project.
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="BclBuildAddProjectReferenceProperties"
          BeforeTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration"
          Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <_BclBuildProjectReferenceProperties>BclBuildReferencingProject=$(MSBuildProjectFullPath);BclBuildReferencingProjectConfig=$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages.config</_BclBuildProjectReferenceProperties>
      <_BclBuildProjectReferenceProperties Condition="'$(SkipValidatePackageReferences)' != ''">$(_BclBuildProjectReferenceProperties);SkipValidatePackageReferences=$(SkipValidatePackageReferences)</_BclBuildProjectReferenceProperties>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference>
        <AdditionalProperties>$(_BclBuildProjectReferenceProperties);%(ProjectReference.AdditionalProperties)</AdditionalProperties>
      </ProjectReference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                            BclBuildSetRunningFullBuild

    Determines when a full build is running as opposed to a single target.
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="BclBuildSetRunningFullBuild"
          BeforeTargets="BuildOnlySettings">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <BclBuildRunningFullBuild>true</BclBuildRunningFullBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                    GetTargetPath/BclBuildGetTargetPath

    MSBuild will only build a target once for a given set of properties.

    We need that single build of GetTargetPath to run during project reference resolution, so that we can detect a 
    referencing project that doesn't have Bcl.Build.

    To accomplish this we replace GetTargetPath with BclBuildGetTargetPath when running a full build.
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <Target
      Name="GetTargetPath"
      Condition="'$(BclBuildRunningFullBuild)' != 'true'"
      DependsOnTargets="$(GetTargetPathDependsOn)"
      Returns="$(TargetPath)"/>

  <Target
      Name="BclBuildGetTargetPath"
      Condition="'$(BclBuildRunningFullBuild)' == 'true'"
      AfterTargets="GetTargetPath"
      Returns="$(TargetPath)">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Reset BclBuildRunningFullBuild, it will be set again when doing a full build. -->
      <BclBuildRunningFullBuild>false</BclBuildRunningFullBuild>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

  <!-- 
    ===================================================================================================================
                                                                                 BclBuildValidateNugetPackageReferences

    This target validates that any Nuget packages installed in the current project are also installed in projects 
    referencing the current project.

    This is necessary because Nuget packages contain more than just simple references.  Installing the package ensures
        1. The right set of references for the target framework are added
        2. Config file transforms are applied
        3. Project installation scripts are run

    For all packages listed as installed for the current project in packages config, if the package ID matches one
    specified in @(ValidatePackages), ensure that the same package is installed in the referencing project. 

    This target can be disabled for a project reference by setting SkipValidatePackageReferences=true for the reference:
    <ProjectReference Include="..\pcl\pcl.csproj">
      <Project>{664a9e98-fac7-4567-a046-0dde95fddb48}</Project>
      <Name>pcl</Name>
      <Properties>SkipValidatePackageReferences=true</Properties>
    </ProjectReference>

    This target can be disabled for all references to a project by adding the following:
    <PropertyGroup>
      <SkipValidatePackageReferences>true</SkipValidatePackageReferences>
    </PropertyGroup>
    ===================================================================================================================
    -->
  <UsingTask TaskName="ValidatePackageReferences" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Microsoft.Bcl.Build.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="BclBuildValidateNugetPackageReferences"
          Condition="'$(BclBuildRunningFullBuild)' != 'true' AND '$(SkipValidatePackageReferences)' != 'true' AND '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'"
          BeforeTargets="GetTargetPath">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ValidatePackages Include="Microsoft.Bcl"/>
      <ValidatePackages Include="Microsoft.Bcl.Async"/>
      <ValidatePackages Include="Microsoft.Bcl.Compression"/>
      <ValidatePackages Include="Microsoft.Net.Http"/>
    </ItemGroup>

    <ValidatePackageReferences Packages="@(ValidatePackages)"
                               ReferencingProject="$(BclBuildReferencingProject)"
                               ReferencingProjectPackagesConfig="$(BclBuildReferencingProjectConfig)"
                               ReferencedProject="$(MSBuildProjectFullPath)"
                               ReferencedProjectPackagesConfig="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\packages.config"
                               TreatWarningsAsErrors="$(TreatWarningsAsErrors)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

But, when I try to build the project, This give me an error:

```
Error   MSB4018 The "EnsureBindingRedirects" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentException: Path cannot be the empty string or all whitespace.
   at System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
   at Roxel.BuildTasks.EnsureBindingRedirects.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Visual Studio Version: 2017 - 15.6.6
I tried to reinstall Microsoft DotNet Core SDK's 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0.

Obs.: The Project that produces error, is targeted to .Net Framework 4.0 (That I have installed on machine).

Comment: Did you find the solution for this?